# ZoomIn and ZoomOut in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I want to open one URL in UIWebView, I am able to open URL but It's rending big like Ref : [image]

I want to open URL capture full view or we can say all the contents of the url will be visible at a time and user can pinch( ZoomIn and ZoomOut like UIScrollView) the web page. How can I implement this. Thank you.

I want to show URL in WebView like this . [image]

Comment: it's already implemented in the uiwebview..isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Set `scalesPageToFit` property to `YES` .

```
  myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: It is not helpful for me. This is my sample code. NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
 
 
 
 //Create a URL object.
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 
 //URL Requst Object
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 
 
 
 //webviewBuyCD.scalesPageToFit = YES;

 //Load the request in the UIWebView.
 [webviewBuyCD loadRequest:requestObj];